# WebPage display value different from the one in the source code

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

I am new to the web and "php" and am currently working with the "simple_html_dom.php". I am trying to fetch the value from the web page based on the "data-reactid". Once I get it in, I see that the value fetched is the different from the one that is displayed.
By doing inspect element - I see the correct value.
By going to the source code - I see the value that is different from the one that is displayed and fetched into my code. Please find the screenshots below.

Display&Inspect
[image]

SourceCode

[image]

Method, that is extracting the data.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mds5r.png)
Parameters:
`$webPage` - web page where the product is described.
`$pattern` - 'price' => 'div[data-reactid*="0.5.0.1.0.0.0.0.1.3.0"]'
`$searchLevel`- 0.

The question would be , why is there this difference and how it is possible to extract the correct value (the displayed one).

Br,
Aleks.

Comment: May be they are modifying their dom with `js`. If that is the case, php won't be much helpfull to resolve this.

Comment: hum, if not with a php, is it possible to fetch the correct value?

Comment: Basically, client side language has to be used :)

Comment: phantom js - headless browser is an answer :)